# Subquery returned more than 1 value. in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT  F_Asset_Code,  F_Unit_Price,   F_ServiceStart  
FROM T_Assets
  where F_ServiceStart <= '2016-10-31' and F_ServiceStart<>'1900-01-01' 
  and F_Asset_CurrentValue <> '0.00' or F_Asset_CurrentValue is null
```

if i add condition like this am getting error

```
SELECT  F_Asset_Code,  F_Unit_Price,  (select F_SLM_Years from T_L1Category 
where F_L1Cat_Code=T_Assets.F_L1Cat_Code) as F_SLM_Years,  F_ServiceStart  
FROM T_Assets
  where F_ServiceStart <= '2016-10-31' and F_ServiceStart<>'1900-01-01' 
  and F_Asset_CurrentValue <> '0.00' or F_Asset_CurrentValue is null
```

Error :

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: The error message should be clear enough, your subquery cant return more than one value.

Comment: Use Top 1 in the inner select. What are you trying to accomplish? Top 1 might not suit your needs.

Comment: Error itself clear F_SLM_Years from T_L1Category having more than one value for that F_L1Cat_Code.

Comment: Evidently `F_L1Cat_Code=T_Assets.F_L1Cat_Code` doesn't result in a single value either add a distinct or add limiting criteria.  Limiting the results to a top may hide a problem if the values for F_SLM_YEARS could be different.

Comment: @WEI_DBA - good idea. Hide the logical error. *Either* they were expecting there to be only one value but there's more than one - they should investigate where their assumptions broke down - *or* they're expecting multiple values and actually need a way to deal with them - aggregation or transformation to a join.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever. Agreed, but I did follow up with a logical question.

Comment: but i need to get all value

Comment: @user3262364 Then you should be using a join.

Comment: @xQbert Thanks ,i can use left join right?

Comment: @user3262364. You should have explained your expected results better in your question. This would have saved a lot of time and given you a quicker answer.

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1**: Find out data that caused the problem in T_L1Category

```
SELECT  *
FROM    T_L1Category
WHERE   F_L1Cat_Code IN ( SELECT    F_L1Cat_Code
                          FROM      ( SELECT    F_L1Cat_Code ,
                                                COUNT(1) 1
                                      FROM      T_L1Category
                                      GROUP BY  F_L1Cat_Code
                                      HAVING    COUNT(1) > 1
                                    ) tb1 )
```

**Step 2**: By result of Step 1, find out why where are more than one records in T_L1Category with the same `F_L1Cat_Code`

**Step 3**: By result of Step 2, you can use method below to solve the problem

```
a)
SELECT TOP 1
        F_SLM_Years
FROM    T_L1Category
WHERE   F_L1Cat_Code = T_Assets.F_L1Cat_Code
ORDER BY XXX

b)
SELECT  F_SLM_Years
FROM    T_L1Category
WHERE   F_L1Cat_Code = T_Assets.F_L1Cat_Code
        AND XXX = YYY

c)
SELECT DISTINCT
        F_SLM_Years
FROM    T_L1Category
WHERE   F_L1Cat_Code = T_Assets.F_L1Cat_Code
```

Comment: Besides, I think use [F_Asset_CurrentValue > '0' or F_Asset_CurrentValue like '-' ] instead of [F_Asset_CurrentValue <> '0.00'] might be better

Comment: [F_Asset_CurrentValue > '0' or F_Asset_CurrentValue like '-%' ]  when F_Asset_CurrentValue = '0.000'

Answer (score 1):

Using a left join should work, I assume you're expecting some null values.

This also assumes you want multiple values returned for F_SLM_Years; and based on comments I believe that assumption is correct.

Also note: You should also use ()'s around the OR and appropriate and in case someone later adds a condition or re-arranges the order of the where. Such as:

`and (F_Asset_CurrentValue <> '0.00' or F_Asset_CurrentValue is null)`

However I prefer a different approach to the or.  A `coalesce` can avoid the OR entirely.  Also it seemed odd to be comparing a what I believe is a currency data type (numeric) to a string so I eliminated the single quotes and .00.

```
SELECT  F_Asset_Code,  F_Unit_Price, F_SLM_Years,  F_ServiceStart  
FROM T_Assets
LEFT JOIN T_L1Category
  ON T_L1Category.F_L1Cat_Code=T_Assets.F_L1Cat_Code
WHERE F_ServiceStart <= '2016-10-31' 
  and F_ServiceStart<>'1900-01-01' 
  and coalesce(F_Asset_CurrentValue,0) <> 0
```

Lastly the F_ServiceStart<> '1900-01-01'  seems odd.  Is this a hardcoded system value or really a null being displayed as 1/1/1900?  in which case you would need to eliminate Nulls?

`and F_ServiceStart is not null` instead of `F_ServiceStart<>'1900-01-01'`?

Answer (score 0):

When you get an error like this, you must first understand **why** you are getting more than one value and whether the business rules mean you need to show all of them or, if you should have only one, then what business rule do you you need to use to limit it to only one. This is not something you can do willy nilly. You need to understand the data to understand what you should do to correct this. All of the following pieces of code, depending on the actual data, could clear the error, only one might give the correct answer:

Picking the highest value

```
SELECT  F_Asset_Code,  F_Unit_Price,  (select top 1 F_SLM_Years from T_L1Category 
where F_L1Cat_Code=T_Assets.F_L1Cat_Code order by F_SLM_Years desc) as F_SLM_Years,  F_ServiceStart  
FROM T_Assets
  where F_ServiceStart <= '2016-10-31' and F_ServiceStart<>'1900-01-01' 
  and F_Asset_CurrentValue <> '0.00' or F_Asset_CurrentValue is null
```

Picking the lowest value

```
SELECT  F_Asset_Code,  F_Unit_Price,  (select MIN(F_SLM_Years) from T_L1Category 
where F_L1Cat_Code=T_Assets.F_L1Cat_Code ) as F_SLM_Years,  F_ServiceStart  
FROM T_Assets
  where F_ServiceStart <= '2016-10-31' and F_ServiceStart<>'1900-01-01' 
  and F_Asset_CurrentValue <> '0.00' or F_Asset_CurrentValue is null
```

Aggregating the values

```
SELECT  F_Asset_Code,  F_Unit_Price,  (select SUM(F_SLM_Years) from T_L1Category 
where F_L1Cat_Code=T_Assets.F_L1Cat_Code ) as F_SLM_Years,  F_ServiceStart  
FROM T_Assets
  where F_ServiceStart <= '2016-10-31' and F_ServiceStart<>'1900-01-01' 
  and F_Asset_CurrentValue <> '0.00' or F_Asset_CurrentValue is null
```

Picking a single value based on an additional where condition (assuming the where condition 100% of the time would return only 1 value!)

```
SELECT  F_Asset_Code,  F_Unit_Price,  (select F_SLM_Years from T_L1Category 
where F_L1Cat_Code=T_Assets.F_L1Cat_Code  and F_L1Cat_Code= 'test' ) as F_SLM_Years,  F_ServiceStart  
FROM T_Assets
  where F_ServiceStart <= '2016-10-31' and F_ServiceStart<>'1900-01-01' 
  and F_Asset_CurrentValue <> '0.00' or F_Asset_CurrentValue is null
```

Using a join to return all the records

```
SELECT  F_Asset_Code,  F_Unit_Price, F_SLM_Years,  F_ServiceStart  
FROM T_Assets
LEFT JOIN T_L1Category
  ON T_L1Category.F_L1Cat_Code=T_Assets.F_L1Cat_Code
WHERE F_ServiceStart <= '2016-10-31' 
  and F_ServiceStart<>'1900-01-01' 
  and (F_Asset_CurrentValue <> '0.00' or F_Asset_CurrentValue is null)
```

Using the stuff function to concatenate the multiple results for that one field into a string

```
select F_Asset_Code,  F_Unit_Price, STUFF((SELECT  ' ' + cast(F_SLM_Years as nvarchar) 
        FROM  T_L1Category 
        where F_L1Cat_Code=T_Assets.F_L1Cat_Code
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''
         )
FROM T_Assets
  where F_ServiceStart <= '2016-10-31' and F_ServiceStart<>'1900-01-01' 
  and F_Asset_CurrentValue <> '0.00' or F_Asset_CurrentValue is null
```

Answer (score -1):

You error message is telling you what is wrong with your query.  You cannot use sub-queries like that when they return more than one row of data.

Take that sub query and run it on its own and you will see this.  Change the sub query to only return the one relevant value and you will be fine.

Comment: sir i need to get all value there

Comment: @user3262364  You cannot have more than one row returned in a sub-query when used in a `select` statement.  It is simply impossible.  If you need multiple rows of rows of data you need to use a `join`.